# iam want to creating image and container from root module to call child module using docker as a provider but while doing terraform plan

Tags: module

│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on modules/container/main.tf line 14, in resource "docker_container" "mycontainer":
│   14:   image = var.image
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.image is object with 10 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "image": string required.

i want a solution for my problem given above